# Why is my flex-shrink in my flexbox only working when I have a flex-grow value specified in CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm new to CSS so apologies if this is newbie stuff, but I'm trying to get the images in my flex-box to shrink with resizing the window but it only seems to be working when I have a flex-grow value inputted as well. Which is weird because I know the default flex-shrink value is 1. But elements don't ever seem to be resizing when compressing the window on my laptop. However when I add a flex-grow value, suddenly everything seems to shrink as it should. And then when I add a max-width value to my images (trying to prevent the image to take up the whole next column because I'm also using flex-wrap) suddenly it stops minimizing. It's all confusing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
.flex{
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 800px;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-content: flex-start;
   }

img{
  flex-shrink: 2;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  }
```

The  tag is tied to four images. The flex class is the flex container that holds all the images. The images only compress when I add flex-grow to the  value. I would expect them to shrink by default but they do not and still do not when I add a flex-shrink value to the code. Only after adding flex-grow do they start shrinking. By the way, this is a test code and these are the only lines of code that I'm using so there are no conflicting code.

Comment: we need more code to test (at least the relevant HTML)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.